# Eloquent Relationship Count Constraint

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to write an eloquent query that would work as follows:

```
Tables:
Order
Support Ticket (one to many with the order)
```

Query:
Filter the support tickets and only show the order if the support ticket is less than 45 days old.

I feel like this would be an adaptation of the whereHas() method in Laravel but I am not sure how to implement a filter or a date search on a relationship like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$orders = Order::whereDoesntHave('support_ticket')
    ->orWhereHas('support_ticket', function($query) {
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(45));
    })->get();
```

Where "support_ticket" is the name of the relationship in your Order model.
In this way you can retrieve the orders that doesn't have a support ticket or that have at least one and less than 45 days old.

As you are in Laravel 5 maybe now() is not defined, then you can use:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I see that this is forcing that there must be at least one ticket on the order. Is there a way to use this in a conditional? Like "if it does have a ticket, it must be within the last 45 days"

Comment: think i figured it out, I can add a "whereDoesntHave" and then do "orWhereHas"

Comment: Yes that's it! Let me know if you figured it out!

Comment: @ackerchez edited the answer, tell me if it worked! Maybe you can edit the question so it is all cleared out!